# Rails 4, does not render partials in shared folder and not loading CSS properly for yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml, render, yield

When I load root the header displays and CSS files are loaded properly, but when I go to another page (i.e. `localhost:3000/videos`), the `shared/header` is not displayed and CSS is broken.

When I used Rails 3 with the same layout and shared files with CSS, it displayed properly, what am I missing ? I do not see any changes for rendering and yield in Rails 4.

**views/layouts/application.html.haml**

```
!!! 5
%html(lang="en-US")
  %head
    %title MyFLiX4.0
    %meta(charset="UTF-8")
    %meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    = csrf_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = yield :head
  %body
    %header
      = render 'shared/header'           # This part does not display in yield
    %section.content.clearfix
      = render 'shared/messages'         # This part does not display in yield
      = yield                            # This part does not load CSS properly
    %footer
      &copy 2013 MyFLiX4.0
```

I have partials as follows: 
[views/shared/_header.html.haml](https://github.com/yhagio/myflix4.0/blob/master/app/views/shared/_header.html.haml)  
[views/shared/_messages.html.haml](https://github.com/yhagio/myflix4.0/blob/master/app/views/shared/_messages.html.haml)

**github:** https://github.com/yhagio/myflix4.0/tree/master/app/views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app/controllers/videos_controller.rb, line one should be

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
```

not

```
class VideosController < ActionController::Base
```